# How do I confirm a multi line input in the commandline?

Tags: bash

I have something like this

```
command \
second line of command \
...
...
```

How do I confirm so it executes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The backslash (\) at the end of the line continues the command to the next line. Don't end the last line of the command with a backslash and it will execute the whole command.

If you have an unclosed quote (" or '), the command also won't complete until you close the quote. Also some uncompleted commands are detected and continue to prompt you for the rest of the command. In bash, simply typing 'if' for example won't complete until the shell sees the terminating 'fi'.

Comment: so just 'enter'? Doesn't seem to work, I just get another line of "..."

Comment: What shell are you running? This works for me in sh, bash, csh, and tcsh.

Comment: I just realized that if you have an unclosed quote (" or '), the command also won't complete until you close the quote. Also some uncompleted commands are detected and continue to prompt you for the rest of the command simply typing 'if' for example wont' complete until the shell sees the terminating  'fi' (bash).

Answer (score 3):

The first line not ending with a '\' will execute it.

Comment: not true I keep getting > line after line and only Ctrl+C ends the horrible experience